# Availability of SSO in Outlook addin

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

The Identity API requirement sets lists that the SSO is still in preview for Office addin.

Any tentative dates when SSO will be available for Outlook-addin ?

Comment: This site is about programming, not soothsaying.

Answer (score 2):

SSO is currently available in the [Preview API Requirement Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview?context=outlook/context) for Outlook Add-ins.

Comment: When will it be available in GA ?

Answer (score 0):

It is available in Outlook add-ins (in preview). Please see [SSO in Office Add-ins, Preview status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#preview-status).